# What are the way to generate rss feed for a site which doesn't have own rss?

Tags: java, python, rss

When I use google reader, I found, sometime website doesn't rss support, but somehow google reader produced it, and show it. I want to know how google reader do it. Any programming language solution or just theory will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to pretend I know how google read does it but here's a simple hint:

When a browser loads a page for the first time, he keeps a copy in its cache.
The next time the page needs to be loaded, the browser first checks if the page has changed since the last time it was loaded. If it wasn't, he will simply load the version in the cache, otherwise, he will refetch the page again.

This mechanism is done, as far as I know, using the **HEAD** HTTP operation and the **Last-Modified** header.

This should be your starting point as it manage to rapidly find out if some new content was published.

The next step would be to use some clever algorithms to define what the change was, if it's relevant enough to be considered as a new content and how to present it.

[Reference](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)